# Error with generating sequences when graphing plots in R

Tags: r, plot, seq

Simply trying to generate a function for plotting area under the curve for a z score or set of z scores, but when I give two z scores with `zshade(c(1,2))` I get the following error:

```
Error in seq.default(z1, z2, 0.01) : 'to' must be of length 1
```

But I'm not sure why this is the case, I double checked `z2` and it's indeed of length 1 so I'm unsure where the error is.

```
zshade = function(z, shade = "left") {
  # If more than 2 z scores are given
  if (length(z) > 2) {
    stop("Error: Too many z scores given!")
  }

  # If two z scores are given
  if (length(z) > 1) {
    z1 = min(z)
    z2 = max(z)
    cord.x = c(z1, seq(z1, z2, 0.01), z2)
    cord.y = c(0, dnorm(seq(z1, z2, 0.01)), 0)
    curve(dnorm(x, 0, 1), xlim = c(-4, 4), main = "Standard Normal", 
      ylab = "", xlab = "")
    polygon(cord.x, cord.y, col = "skyblue")
  }

  # If a single z score is given
  if (shade == "left") {
    z1 = -4
    z2 = z
    cord.x = c(z1, seq(z1, z2, 0.01), z2)
    cord.y = c(0, dnorm(seq(z1, z2, 0.01)), 0)
    curve(dnorm(x, 0, 1), xlim = c(-4, 4), main = "Standard Normal Curve", 
        ylab = "", xlab = "")
    polygon(cord.x, cord.y, col = "skyblue")
  }
  if (shade == "right") {
    z1 = z
    z2 = 4
    cord.x = c(z1, seq(z1, z2, 0.01), z2)
    cord.y = c(0, dnorm(seq(z1, z2, 0.01)), 0)
    curve(dnorm(x, 0, 1), xlim = c(-4, 4), main = "Standard Normal Curve", 
        ylab = "", xlab = "")
    polygon(cord.x, cord.y, col = "skyblue")
  }
}
```

zshade(c(1,2))

Comment: Where is the code making the function call `zshade(z1, z2, 0.01) ` ?  Can you clearly see what the problem is?

Comment: Look at line 21: `z2 = z`. There you go, from there on `z2` is of length 2.

Comment: Ahh, totally see what I did wrong here. Just making a silly mistake of jumping the gun and forgetting a simple line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake, see code below...

```
zshade = function(z, shade = "left") {
# If more than 2 z scores are given
if (length(z) > 2) {
  stop("Error: Too many z scores given!")
}

# If two z scores are given
if (length(z) > 1) {
  z1 = min(z)
  z2 = max(z)
  cord.x = c(z1, seq(z1, z2, 0.01), z2)
  cord.y = c(0, dnorm(seq(z1, z2, 0.01)), 0)
  curve(dnorm(x, 0, 1), xlim = c(-4, 4), main = "Standard Normal", 
        ylab = "", xlab = "")
  polygon(cord.x, cord.y, col = "skyblue")
}

if (length(z)==1) {
  # If a single z score is given
  if (shade == "left") {
    z1 = -4
    z2 = z
    cord.x = c(z1, seq(z1, z2, 0.01), z2)
    cord.y = c(0, dnorm(seq(z1, z2, 0.01)), 0)
    curve(dnorm(x, 0, 1), xlim = c(-4, 4), main = "Standard Normal Curve", 
          ylab = "", xlab = "")
    polygon(cord.x, cord.y, col = "skyblue")
  }
  if (shade == "right") {
    z1 = z
    z2 = 4
    cord.x = c(z1, seq(z1, z2, 0.01), z2)
    cord.y = c(0, dnorm(seq(z1, z2, 0.01)), 0)
    curve(dnorm(x, 0, 1), xlim = c(-4, 4), main = "Standard Normal Curve", 
          ylab = "", xlab = "")
    polygon(cord.x, cord.y, col = "skyblue")
  }
 }
}
```